# Powershell array values being overwritten

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm at a bit of a loss to understand why this code isn't doing what I think it should.

This is part of a larger plan but in essence I'm attempting to fill part of an array with entries from a text file, though I've replaced that bit with a hard coded array. The end result is the same.

```
$users = 12345,23456,34567,45678,56789,67890

$a = New-Object PSCustomObject
$a = $a|Select ID
$collection = @()

$users|%{
    $a.ID = $_
    $collection += $a
}

$collection|ft -a
```

This outputs the following:

```
   ID
   --
67890
67890
67890
67890
67890
67890
```

If you output the array to screen as it gets built, you can watch the values get replaced each time with the most recent entry.
What's the fault? Is there something unusual with the way I'm initialising the $a variable or the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PS is adding a reference to the object itself into the array, rather than the object contents at the time it's added. Changing the value of `$a.ID` at any point changes the contents displayed by `$collection`.

To fix this, you can move the initialization for `$a` within the `%` statement like so:

```
$users = 12345,23456,34567,45678,56789,67890

$collection = @()

$users|%{
    $a = New-Object PSCustomObject
    $a = $a|Select ID
    $a.ID = $_
    $collection += $a
}

$collection|ft -a
```

or just simply add `$a.ID` to `$collection` if you only want the ID value in that array.

Answer (score 2):

It's doing that because there is only one object ($a), and all your loop is doing is changing the value of the one property (ID), and adding another reference to it to the array.

You need to create a new object for each cycle of the loop:

```
$users = 12345,23456,34567,45678,56789,67890

$a = New-Object PSCustomObject
$a = $a|Select ID
$collection = @()

$users|%{
    $a = New-Object PSCustomObject
    $a = $a|Select ID
    $a.ID = $_
    $collection += $a
}

$collection|ft -a
```

Comment: You don't need to initialize `$a` outside of the `%` loop in your example code - it will be initialized on loop execution.

Comment: True, and you could replace the whole object creation with [PSCustomObject]@{ID=$_}, and eliminate the array addition with simple indirection.  For the moment it seemed better to demonstrate using the OP's original code.

Comment: Fair, it just seemed strange to show duplicate code.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish here, really... but what if you try it like this?

```
$collection += $a.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You create one object ($a). You then add this one object to $collection multiple times. Each time you add it you change its .ID property value. So at the end you have $collection holding many copies of this one object. So you get many copies of that one ID value. Create a new object each time inside the loop if you want multiple objects with different values.